# Partition level Access on Data stored in snowdfl

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and was exploring on snowflake on AWS. When the data is stored in snowflake , i understood that we can create and manage data in partitions similar to what we do in hive. Hive doesn't allow me to have partition level user access management. Can I do that with snowflake ? if yes , how do we do and how its managed on storage layer on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Snowflake, you have no direct access to the underlying storage, you can only use the access mechanisms that Snowflake provides. Snowflake manages all the provision, management and layout of your data on the underlying storage entirely transparently. So you can't "create and manage data in partitions similar to what we do in hive"

If you want to understand more about how this storage works you can read about micro-partitioning [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html)

In the vast majority of cases there is no need to interfere with how Snowflake is laying out your data but there is the functionality available to force how the data is clustered - though Snowflake suggests that this is only ever useful on multi-terabyte tables. You can read about clustering tables [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#)

Snowflake does have the concept of "External Tables" - these are tables that appear in the Snowflake DBs as normal tables but their data is actually held in S3 (or Azure Blob or GCP storage) that you own and manage rather than Snowflake. These tables can be convenient to create/use but perform significantly worse than tables held directly in Snowflake: when the data is loaded into Snowflake it might be still ultimately stored on S3 but it is compressed, converted into columnar format and held in micro-partitions - so very different in structure to the files you can see in your S3 buckets

Comment: Ok . Thanks much.. my question on this is that how can we manage access to different sets of data.. like i have class 1 data and class2 data in a single table. I want person A to access class 1 data and person B to have access on class2 data. How do i achieve that in IAM policy?

Comment: I may not have explained clearly but you can only manage Snowflake data using Snowflake functionality. IAM is AWS functionality and so is irrelevant to this discussion. If you want to display different sets of data from the same table to different users then you'll probably need to use views